# Having an issue in deleting an uploaded .apk from test lab on google cloud platform

Tags: firebase, firebase-test-lab

Inside the google cloud platform, in the test lab, I uploaded an .apk and we have a new version that we need to test. How do i upload a new version? and how do i delete the old version? I can find no documentation on this matter at all.
Referring to the Test Lab found in firebase under Quality
https://console.firebase.google.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Steps to run a new tests in the Firebase Console:

1. Navigate to the [Firebase Console](https://console.firebase.google.com)
2. Select your Firebase project in case you have multiple.
3. In the left-side navigation, click **Test Lab** under the **Quality** section.
4. It will show you your most recent test. There is a button on the top right of the test table named **Run test**. Click it and select what type of test you want to run.
5. On the next screen you will have options to upload the app and test APK.

Here's a picture what the button looks like:

[image: Run test button in Test Lab]

Note, you can also do this from the command-line with [gcloud](https://firebase.google.com/docs/test-lab/android/command-line).

Comment: yeah the issue is I wanted to delete the old test, and google should allow you to do so.

Answer (score 0):

Please note that there's no need to delete old APKs. Every time you run a test in Test Lab, simply provide the current APK you wish to test.